# Passing char arrays to functions with toupper

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers, char

Long time lurker needing help that I am not able to find via search. okay, I'm lying, I found something but it hasn't helped me.

What I'm trying to do is create a char array with strings and display the, pass them to a function that will uppercase the alpha characters (which should only be one) and then display the char array again with uppercase letters.

I can't get this to work. I found through the search bar and it says I should be able to pass a pointer to a char array and uppercase via

```
*d = toupper(*d);
```

but it's just not working. Can anyone shed some light on the subject? Thanks!

It compiles by using gcc via the command prompt and it gives be a "Bus 10 error" and on Xcode I get this: "Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=2, address=memorylocation)"

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main() {

void print_data(char *info[]);
void convert_data(char *info[]);
char *data[] = { "000a", "000b", "000c", "000d", "000e" };

print_data(data);
printf("\n");
convert_data(data);
print_data(data);

return 0;

}

void print_data(char *info[]) {
    int n;
    for (n=0; n < 5; n++) {
        char *p = info[n];
        while (*p != '\0') {
            printf("%c", *(p++));
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

void convert_data(char *info[]) {
    int n;
    for (n=0; n<5; n++) {
        char *d = info[n];
        while (*d != '\0') { // I THINK THIS IS THE PROBLEM
            *d = toupper(*d); // RIGHT HERE TOO
             d++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Firstly, you have not adequately described the current (incorrect) behaviour of your program. What is it actually doing? But for starters: `while (*d != '\0')`, that is an infinete loop as `d` is not changed within the loop anywhere.

Comment: I added d++, but before it even goes there it gives me an error .

Comment: "gives me an error".. which is? And update your code with the `d++` if indeed you have that otherwise how can we focus on what your actual problem is?

Comment: It compiles by using gcc via the command prompt and it gives be a "Bus 10 error" and on Xcode I get this: "Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=2, address=memorylocation)"

Comment: Put that in your question body. Not as a comment. It forms a key part of your question. And have you run your program in a debugger to find out exactly which line of code is causing the memory access error?

Comment: No, I'm sorry. I'm not very familiar with the debugger. I apologize, i'm still a little new to this.

Comment: Oh, your `data` contains constant strings. You can not change that memory.

Comment: Pardon my ignorance but is there a way to do what I'm trying to do? There has to be a way, or similar way, no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
char *data[] = { "000a", "000b", "000c", "000d", "000e" };
```

That declares an array of `char` pointers and intialises each of the array entries to point to a constant string. Constant strings cannot be modified and hence the memory access error when `toupper` is called to modify any of those strings.

There are many ways to fix this. But they all boil down to allocating memory for the string data. A quick way (but not necessarily the best) is to change the `data` declaration so that each array entry is an array of `char`. Like so:

```
char data[][5] = { "000a", "000b", "000c", "000d", "000e" };
```

Then also need to change the functions that take in `data` to be the correct type:

```
void print_data(char info[][5]);
void convert_data(char info[][5]);
```